# App sem consumo de franquia de dados

Tags: android, mobile, windows-phone, redes

Olá.
Estou pesquisando para ver com funcionam alguns aplicativos que permitem o seu uso sem que seja consumido dados da franquia de internet. O iFood, por exemplo, possui este recurso, dentre outros como Magazine Luiza, etc.

Alguem sabeme dar mais informações de como isso é feito? A empresa onde trabalho está querendo oferecer isto em seus aplicativos para os seus empregados.

Obrigado.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que isto é fora de escopo. O que posso dizer é que se o país fosse sério nada disso ocorreria porque tem lei que diz que não pode ser feito.

Comment: @Maniero poderia explicar melhor sua afirmação? achei curioso a duvida e tambem a sua afirmação, gostaria de entender mais.

Comment: Se eu não me engano isso deve ter alguma parceria com operadoras de celular.

Comment: Acredito que de alguma forma ou de outra o consumo de dados é pago, mas gostaria de saber como, entende? Se for o caso de contratação de algum serviço esse nao seria o problema, já que a empresa bancaria esta contratação. Seria mais o caso de entender o processo.

Comment: http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2014/lei/l12965.htm

Comment: Acho que obtive uma luz. E não acredito que seja ilegal, pois trata-se de uma parceria. Vejam o fragmento extraido da materia no endereço: https://www.tecmundo.com.br/apps/113432-comemore-ifood-nao-consome-dados-moveis-franquia.htm

"A empresa responsável pelo iFood afirma que a novidade foi implementada após “pesquisas em todas as regiões onde a empresa atua”. 
Para isso, foi necessário realizar uma parceria com as operadoras já mencionadas. Vale dizer que ainda existe grande participação da tecnologia da Datami ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui descobrir. Chama-se Navegação Patrocinada, e todas as operadoras oferecem este serviço. Para que seja legal, deve-se fazer o contrato diretamente com a operadora sem intermediários, e cada operadora pode cobrar um preço pelo serviço.

Abraços.